# Mongoose async/await with Koa get stuck on await Model.findOne().exec()

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await, babeljs, koa2

I have an Koa 2 application, and a post to /signup is handled by this function:

```
import User from 'models/user';

export const signup = async (ctx, next) => {
  const { email, password } = ctx.request.body;
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (existingUser) {
      ctx.body = { error: 'Email is in use' };
      return next();
    }

    const user = new User({
      email,
      password,
    });
    await user.save();
    ctx.body = { success: true };
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
  return next();
};
```

The funtion receives correct data but the `await User.findOne().exec();` never returns and gets stuck.

I think the problem is there because if I remove, code is executed normally. If I switch to Promise like... `find().then` It works too. 
async/await is working either, because If I change to a await fetch() (to emulate async) it works... but here is my babel config

```
{
  "presets" : ["latest", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"]
    }]
  ]
}
```

mongoose is version 4.7.0

Comment: Your code doesn't show you using `.exec()` (although it's probably not strictly necessary to use it). Also, are you sure that it doesn't throw an exception? Your code calls `next` twice when an exception occurs (once with the error argument, and then with `return next`).

Comment: ah sorry .. copied an old code.. but doesn't work either... and no exceptions... and already fixed the two calls... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started another application and t is working now. Don't know what happened.
Maybe new version fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote very similar app, but all worked fine. What type of promises you use? I mean you use native JS promisese or Mongoose promises? With mongoose promises I had problems so I change it for native JS:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = Promise; // Use native Promises

mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoose.uri'), config.get('mongoose.options'));
...
module.exports = mongoose;
```

Comment: you should not ask for clarifications in your answer, comments are for clarifications if any are needed

Comment: I started another app these days... and it  is working now... Don't know what happened .. CLosing